# simplest way to check for just spaces in ruby

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, testing, spaces

So I know in ruby that x.nil? will test if x is null.

What is the simplest way to test if x equals ' ', or '  '(two spaces), or '   '(three spaces), etc?

Basically, I'm wondering what the best way to test if a variable is all whitespace?

Comment: let me actually clarify my question because it wasn't totally clear... im actually executing this in the context of an if statement.  therefore im checking x.nil? and i also want x.(there is only whitespace here so i consider it nil) to both be conditionally evaluated

Comment: @user301752 when you say `nil` do you mean an empty string? They aren't the same in Ruby. (Open an `irb` session and check: `x = ''; x.nil?`.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
s =~ /\A\s*\Z/
```

Regex solution. Here's a [short ruby regex tutorial](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/regexp.html).

Comment: thanks!  just started learning ruby and didnt realize that =~ would conditionally evaluate regular expression  that is pretty sweet

Comment: @Stefan I think you want `/^\s+$/` since the `*` will match too much (e.g., you get a match for an empty string - no spaces at all).

Comment: I considered '' as all whitespace. This may or may not be correct in the domain of the problem, but I didn't think the question was worded in such a way to make either * or + incorrect.

Comment: Better to use anchors `\A` and `\Z` instead of `^` and `$` -- the string `"abc\n   \ndef"` will match your regex.

Comment: @StefanKendall link is broken

Answer (score 36):

If you are using Rails, you can simply use:

```
x.blank?
```

This is safe to call when x is nil, and returns true if x is nil or all whitespace.

If you aren't using Rails you can get it from the `activesupport` gem. Install with `gem install activesupport`. In your file either `require 'active_support/core_ext` to get all active support extensions to the base classes, or `require 'active_support/core_ext/string'` to get just the extensions to the `String` class. Either way, the `blank?` method will be available after the require.

Comment: By the way I apologize to Rubyists for dragging Rails into what was otherwise a nice, pure Ruby discussion. It's just a nice pattern to emulate.

Comment: @david-miani It's a shame there is no way I can +1 your edit, because it's an excellent one. It's a bad sort of over-optimizing to pluck code out of ActiveSupport when AS already supports including just the features you need.

Answer (score 30):

"best" depends on the context, but here is a simple way.

```
some_string.strip.empty?
```

Answer (score 6):

If `x` is all whitespace, then `x.strip` will be the empty string. So you can do:

```
if not x.nil? and x.strip.empty? then
    puts "It's all whitespace!"
end
```

Alternatively, using a regular expression, `x =~ /\S/` will return false if and only if `x` is all whitespace characters:

```
if not (x.nil? or x =~ /\S/) then
    puts "It's all whitespace!"
end
```

Comment: Mladen was referring to a downvote that was on your answer, not accusing you of downvoting others.

Comment: Right, sorry for not being clear. @miorel, you have +1 from me, both are cool ideas, you can even use `!~` in the latter and get the boolean result straight.

Comment: Strictly speaking `/\S/` doesn't show you that a string is all whitespace. It determines whether there is anything in the string that *isn't* whitespace. This can sometimes matter - at least, if you consider an empty string to be different from a string that is all whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "  " 

a.each_byte do |x|
  if x == 32
    puts "space"
  end
end
```

Comment: To the downvoter, it would be good to know what's wrong with the answer ( or how is this not useful )

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but this is neither the simplest solution, nor is checking for 32 going to catch all whitespace.

Comment: The question was ambiguous about whether he wants spaces or all whitespace characters (including tabs, newlines, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I think you can extend the String class and define a  `spaces?` method as follows:

```
$ irb
>> s = " "
=> " "
>> s.spaces?
NoMethodError: undefined method `spaces?' for " ":String
    from (irb):2
>> class String
>>     def spaces?
>>         x = self =~ /^\s+$/
>>         x == 0
>>     end
>> end
=> nil
>> s.spaces?
=> true
>> s = ""
=> ""
>> s.spaces?
=> false
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

**s.include?(" ")**

*Examples:*

```
s = "A B C D"
s.include?(" ") #=> true

s = "ABCD"
s.include?(" ") #=> false
```

Answer (score -1):

Yet another :) `string.all? { |c| c == ' ' }`